# calculate sum of values in dataframe based on values in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, rows, rowsum

I have a dataframe in R in which values correspond to value **estimates** and their **margin of error** (MoE).

**Column names** consist of a *pattern*, an *indicator character* (e = estimate, m = margin of error) and an *ID* that matches estimate and margin of error.
So, the column names look like "XXXe1, XXXm1, XXXe2, XXXm2, ...".

#### Goal

I am trying to create a function to (for each row)

1. Calculate the **sum of the estimates**. (That is pretty straightforward.)
2. Calculate the **aggregated margin of error**. This is the square root of the sum of the squares of each MoE.
3. Condition: the MoE of estimates marked as 0 should only be added once.

Examples:

- In row 20, the aggregated MoE should only be `sqrt(123^2)`.
- In row 13, B01001e4 and B01001e5 are 0, so their MoE is only counted once.

So far, I have done the following to build a function that does this:

```
estimate_aggregator <- function(DF_to_write_on, New_column_name, source_df, pattern){

  subset_df <- source_df[, grepl(pattern, names(source_df))] # I subset all the columns named with the pattern, regardless of whether they are estimate or margin of error
  subset_df_e <- source_df[, grepl(paste0(pattern, "e"), names(source_df))] # I create a table with only the estimated values to perform the sum

  DF_to_write_on[paste0(New_column_name, "_e")]<- rowSums(subset_df_e) # I write a new column in the new DF with the rowSums of the estimates values, having calculated the new estimate

  return(DF)
}
```

What I am missing: a way to write in the new dataframe the result of selecting the XXXmYY values of those columns that have no 0 value in their corresponding estimate. If there is one or more 0 in the estimates, then I should include the MoE 123 in the calculation only once.

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this? I see that my struggle is on dealing with several columns at once and the fact that the values on the XXXeYY columns determine the selection of the XXXmYY ones.

#### Expected output

```
row1: DF_to_write_on[paste0(New_column_name,"_m") <- sqrt(176^2 + 117^2+22^2 + 123^2)
row2: DF_to_write_on[paste0(New_column_name,"_m") <- sqrt(123^2)

   B01001e1 B01001m1 B01001e2 B01001m2 B01001e3 B01001m3 B01001e4 B01001m4 B01001e5 B01001m5
15      566      176      371      117       14       22        0      123        0      123
20        0      123        0      123        0      123        0      123        0      123
```

#### Data

```
structure(list(B01001e1 = c(1691L, 2103L, 975L, 2404L, 866L, 
2140L, 965L, 727L, 1602L, 1741L, 948L, 1771L, 1195L, 1072L, 566L, 
1521L, 2950L, 770L, 1624L, 0L), B01001m1 = c(337L, 530L, 299L, 
333L, 264L, 574L, 227L, 266L, 528L, 498L, 320L, 414L, 350L, 385L, 
176L, 418L, 672L, 226L, 319L, 123L), B01001e2 = c(721L, 1191L, 
487L, 1015L, 461L, 1059L, 485L, 346L, 777L, 857L, 390L, 809L, 
599L, 601L, 371L, 783L, 1215L, 372L, 871L, 0L), B01001m2 = c(173L, 
312L, 181L, 167L, 170L, 286L, 127L, 149L, 279L, 281L, 152L, 179L, 
193L, 250L, 117L, 234L, 263L, 155L, 211L, 123L), B01001e3 = c(21L, 
96L, 70L, 28L, 33L, 90L, 12L, 0L, 168L, 97L, 72L, 10L, 59L, 66L, 
14L, 0L, 35L, 47L, 14L, 0L), B01001m3 = c(25L, 71L, 73L, 26L, 
33L, 79L, 18L, 123L, 114L, 79L, 59L, 15L, 68L, 99L, 22L, 123L, 
31L, 37L, 20L, 123L), B01001e4 = c(30L, 174L, 25L, 91L, 4L, 27L, 
30L, 43L, 102L, 66L, 54L, 85L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 26L, 34L, 27L, 18L, 
0L), B01001m4 = c(26L, 148L, 30L, 62L, 9L, 27L, 25L, 44L, 82L, 
52L, 46L, 48L, 123L, 21L, 123L, 40L, 33L, 32L, 27L, 123L), B01001e5 = c(45L, 
44L, 7L, 46L, 72L, 124L, 45L, 34L, 86L, 97L, 0L, 83L, 0L, 30L, 
0L, 66L, 0L, 23L, 33L, 0L), B01001m5 = c(38L, 35L, 12L, 37L, 
57L, 78L, 36L, 37L, 62L, 97L, 123L, 50L, 123L, 42L, 123L, 59L, 
123L, 31L, 49L, 123L)), .Names = c("B01001e1", "B01001m1", "B01001e2", 
"B01001m2", "B01001e3", "B01001m3", "B01001e4", "B01001m4", "B01001e5", 
"B01001m5"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Sure - will do now

Comment: @akrun I specified the desired outcome that the function should execute to write the new value. Is this enough? let me know!

Comment: should your final output have 2 columns, an estimate and MoE for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds like your desired output should have 2 columns, the row sum of the estimate, and the function of the row margins of errors using the logic you describe. Here is one (somewhat roundabout) solution to that problem.

I saved your data as `df`.

```
# Isolate estimate and MoE dataframes
df_e <- df[,grepl('e', names(df))]
df_m <- df[,grepl('m', names(df))]

# Temporary matrix used to isolate 0 values for MoE, count number of zero occurances, and convert those MoE values to NA
mat <- df_e == 0
mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, cumsum))
df_m[mat > 1] = NA


# Combine with estimate row sum
output_df <- data.frame(
  e = rowSums(df[,grepl('e', names(df))]),
  m = apply(df_m, 1, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2, na.rm = T)))
)

head(output_df)
     e        m
1 2508 382.4173
2 3608 637.5061
3 1564 358.5178
4 3584 380.3512
5 1436 320.9595
6 3440 651.4031
```

Comment: There's a small error in your code: `mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, cumsum));df_m[mat > 1] = NA` will also cause estimates after two zeroes to be discarded, `c(1,2,0,0,3)` will only take the first 3 corresponding margins to be counted. I would use `df_m[df_e!=0 | t(!apply(df_e, 1, duplicated))] <- NA`

Comment: @EmilBode and astrofunkswag, I am trying to run this code (with the change suggested by Emil, replacing those two lines by one). It seems like the resulting  df_m is a matrix with either NA values or 123. This means that the aggregated MoE written in the final column is only based on the values 123. For example, a row with NO 0 values (or no MoE values = 123), gives an aggregated MoE of 0, instead of the sqrt of the sum of the squares. 

Might you need me to show the function I have made, how can I share it with you? ///// MERRY CHRISTMAS!

Comment: My mistake! I set all the _valid_ values to NA, instead of the _invalid_ ones, and didn't test my code... `df_m[df_e==0 | t(apply(df_e, 1, duplicated))] <- NA`  does work. And merry christmas to you too!

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Just a small caveat: if you want to only set to NA values that have an estimate (`df_e == 0`) AND are duplicates, you should be using and `&` operator, not `|` (that's OR). So:

`df_m[df_e==0 & t(apply(df_e, 1, duplicated))] <- NA`

Comment: @arredond YES! you are right! indeed the previous code was not considering the first e==0 but switching it also to NA